# Easy reporting tool for Windows Forms applications, RTF reporting?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reporting, rtf

I have created one Windows Forms application with C# and MySQL (using [MySQL Connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL#Platforms_and_interfaces)). Now I need to create some reports from data in my MySQL database, and print it out.

I've tried [Crystal Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports), Visual Studio 2010 reports and so on, but all seem complicated to use with my entity dataset.

I'm using LINQ to get queries. Is there any way I can create reports like HTML format and simply print them through the application? Someone asked me to send my data as [RTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) and straight without saving or printing it, but I cannot find a good tutorial for creating RTF like that.

Comment: Have you looked at the .net charting?  http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

Comment: Thanks for comment but, what i need is just invoice like report with simple listing of data which is\ in my db.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ReportViewer](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/) is a freely redistributable control that enables embedding reports in applications developed using the .NET Framework. Reports are designed with drag-and-drop simplicity using Report Designer included in Visual Studio 2010. The ReportViewer site will give you all the necessary details. It may be a bit complicated, but it will do what you want. Reporting is a little difficult to understand anyway for a novice user.

I hope you want something like below.

[image]

Comment: cool, thanks ,,, that's what i'm looking for,, your ref link is uite useful.

Comment: This solution does not work if you are using <Page> template in place of <Windows> template in wpf